# No module named app.scripts.file

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to put a file to import under the structure of `app/scripts/file.py`

I then want to call it similar to how I would anything else by doing in my views.py

`from app.scripts.file import *`

doing so gives the following error -

`No module named app.scripts.file`

If I put the file.py directly into the app folder there's no issue.

`from app.file import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a `app/scripts/__init__.py` file ? Without the directory isn't considered as a Python module.

In [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Answer (score 0):

try also adding a `__init__.py` file to that folder. It can be a blank file.